# Foundation 4 Zurb Nav Bar at Bottom instead of Top

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, nav

Is there a simple solution to have a nav bar in Zurb at the bottom of the page instead of the top?

I know that there is the `<nav class="top-bar">` .... but essentially what I am asking for is 
`<nav class="bottom-bar">` where the bar can be placed at the bottom of the page instead of the top...sort of like a footer nav bar?

Answer (score 2):

my solution :

```
.bottom-bar{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

to use just append bottom-bar as in

```
class="top-bar bottom-bar"
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it did not work, I will try again tonight did you put the class="top-bar bottom-bar" inside the nav as such `<nav class="top-bar bottom-bar"></nav>`

Comment: my bad.. i create my own custom.css ontop of zurb one. to use it.. i simple append a new class ontop of top bar like from your example.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can put the Top Bar markup anywhere in the code. Depending on the case, maybe you want to wrap the `nav` in a `div` with class "contain-to-grid" to accommodate it in your grid, as you can read in the [Top Bar Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html).

Comment: The question was if the top fixed can be made as bottom fixed.

Comment: I think "you can put the Top Bar markup anywhere in the code" + what Raja Hafiz said answers the question.